# Wireless driver Lenovo Flex 14 Ubuntu 12 Ultrabook

Tags: 12.04, wireless, brightness, ideapad

I recently bought a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14 and the wireless card is not working and there are issues with the brightness when I start the computer.

I tried the tips that are already given for the same issues for the yoga 13, but I can't bring it to work.

Any ideas how to get the wireless working?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `lspci | grep Network` pelase?

Answer (score 0):

I have bought Lenovo Flex-15 and faced the same problem with WiFi driver. Please check your kernel version on Ubuntu.

```
cat /proc/version
```

Now download the stable backport drivers version which is same or higher version of your kernel from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/). As an example I chose the version for `3.8-rc5`.

After you download the kernel, open a shell/terminal (probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) uncompress it:

```
tar zxvf compat-drivers-3.8-rc5-1-u.tar.gz    # Depends on which archive format
tar jxvf compat-drivers-3.8-rc5-1-u.tar.bz2   # you downloaded. Or just try the
tar Jxvf compat-drivers-3.8-rc5-1-u.tar.xz    # last option. It is supposedly a
tar xf compat-drivers-3.8-rc5-1-u.tar.gz      # catch-all option.
```

then change into the directory that was just expanded:

```
cd compat-drivers-3.8-rc5-1-u
```

Now build the kernel:

```
make
```

And install the built kernel:

```
sudo make install
```

Once installation is done, there will be prompt in shell to reboot for the installed drivers to be enforced.

If in case still you have any problem please let me know, I shall try to provide a solution.